# SQL - Filter out a complete group that has at least one member not part of a specific result

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two SQL TABLES:

**TABLE-1 (Group_Departments)**

```
   Group--------- | ---------Department_ID
    G1 ---------- | ------------- 1
    G1 ---------- | ------------- 43
    G1 ---------- | ------------- 6
    G2 ---------- | ------------- 43
    G2 ---------- | ------------- 46
    G3 ---------- | ------------- 1
    G3 ---------- | ------------- 1
    G4 ---------- | ------------- 46
    G4 ---------- | ------------- 43
    G4 ---------- | ------------- 1
    G4 ---------- | ------------- 32
```

**TABLE-2 (Allowed_Departments)**

```
Department_ID
1
46
43
```

**Target Result Logic:**

1. G1 - Shouldn't show up because it has one department '36' which is not part of the allowed department list.
2. G2 - Should be the part of the result because both departments '43 & 46' are part of the Allowed Departments.
3. G3 - Should show up because '1' is part of allowed departments.
4. G4 - Shouldn't show up. Although three of the departments are part of the allowed departments, but one of it's department '32' is not part of the allowed departments.

The result of the query should be this:

### Result

```
G2
G3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `HAVING` and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT [Group]
FROM Group_Departments gd
LEFT JOIN Allowed_Departments ad
  ON gd.department_id = ad.department_id
GROUP BY [Group]
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ad.department_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1c4320535316fc2d8899114862968fa7)**

---

Alternatively as @Gordon Linoff suggested:

```
SELECT [Group]
FROM Group_Departments gd
LEFT JOIN Allowed_Departments ad
  ON gd.department_id = ad.department_id
GROUP BY [Group]
HAVING COUNT(ad.department_id) = COUNT(*)
```

Comment: I would use `count(ad.department) = count(*)`, but it is the same logic.

Comment: @Lukasz This works completely fine for me. Much to  you for saving my day ;)